# Pyqgis - Removing a layer from the composer legend

Tags: pyqgis, print-composer, legend

I am developing a script to print different map views of a QGIS project.
I want to print all the vector layers in the canvas but I don´t want one of them to appear in the legend. I can`t figure out the way to do it.

Comment: what have you tried and which part does not work? please show us code you developed and which does not work

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
    lyrGroup = QgsLayerTreeGroup()
    for legendLyr in iface.mapCanvas().layers():
        if legendLyr.name() != "layer_you_dont_want"
            lyrGroup.addLayer(legendLyr)
    legend.modelV2().setRootGroup(lyrGroup)
    c.addComposerLegend(legend) # c is your composer
```