# Remove a raster from the composer legend, but display it on the map

Tags: raster, qgis-3, print-composer, legend, pyqgis-3

I'm working with PyQGIS in QGIS 3.10.
I'm trying to remove a layer from the composer legend if it is a raster (but I want to see the raster on the map).
This is my code:

```
for i in self.newLayout.items():
    if isinstance(i,QgsLayoutItemLegend):   
        legend = i 
        legend.setAutoUpdateModel(True)
        for j in range(legend.model().rowCount()):
            modelindex=legend.model().index(j, 0)
            layertreenode=legend.model().index2node(modelindex)
            if layertreenode != QgsLayerTreeGroup :
                if layertreenode.layer().type()==QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
                    layertreenode.setItemVisibilityChecked (False)
        legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
        legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True)
```

It works... but a bit too much: my raster is not anymore visible in the legend, but the layer is set as invisible too (in the composer map and in the canvas)!

I thought I worked only in the legend model! May be I should have used another method like "removeFromLegend"? But I didn't find this anywhere.

More broadly, I think I have difficulties to understand boundaries between layer trees in the table of content and in then composer legend.

EDIT :
I read this thread :
[Remove legend nodes of a categorized layer in a layout legend using PyQgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328032/remove-legend-nodes-of-a-categorized-layer-in-a-layout-legend-using-pyqgis)
an tried

```
if layertreenode.layer().type()==QgsMapLayer.RasterLayer:
    legend.model().removeRows(j,1)
```

It removes the legend item, but il also removes completely the raster from the QGIS project.

Comment: What you are looking for is QgsLegendStyle.Hidden (https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Legend/QgsLegendStyle.html)

Comment: Thank you very much Nil for your answer. I was able to use QgsLegendStyle.Hidden on my legend items (il it is a raster). Unfortunately, this hide the layer name only, and now a blue square appears to represent the raster.

Comment: After you use QgsLegendStyle.Hidden, did you use the layoutItemLegend.updateLegend() and layout.refresh()?

Comment: Yes, I use legend.updateLegend() , legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False), legend.setLegendFilterByMapEnabled(True) and self.newLayout.refresh().
Nota : The blue square is not immediately displayed : there's an empty space instead. It becomes visible when I try to change the legend height.

Comment: I found a workaround here : 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306389/how-to-remove-legend-items-with-pyqgis-without-removing-the-layer
Instead of use autoUpdate Model, you put in the legend layers that you want (and you leave besides the ones you don't want). It should work, but I guess there must be a pyQgis method to do the same as the "minus" button under the legend items list in the parameters!